# What does "t" represent in De Casteljau's algorithm

Tags: math, bezier

Hi everybody I need your help. My question is: what does "t" represent in De Casteljau's algorithm?

We have the following formula to calculate the point Q:

Q=(1−t)P1+tP2, t∈[0,1]

But what does t mean here and why it is between 0 and 1?

Comment: This question is probably better off on http://math.stackexchange.com/. But basically `t` is the ratio of `P1` to `P2`. Half way between the points, `t` is set to `0.5` and `Q = (P1 + P2) / 2` - ie. the average of the two points.

Comment: @Phylogenesis `t` isn't a ratio...

Comment: @Phylogenesis That's incorrect. P1 and P2 needn't be anything that you can compute a ratio of, and even when they are, t isn't their ratio.

Answer (score 3):

The `t` is an interpolation value.

For many computations, it is beneficial to parameterize the curve based on unit length. This basically means that the `t` describes a position on the curve, with `t=0` being the start of the curve, and `t=1` being the end of the curve.

Consider the simplest case of interpolating between two points: Changing the value of `t` between 0 and 1 can be imagined as "walking along the line between the two points". For such a simple interpolation, you can say that the "curve" (i.e. the line between the points) is described by the equation

```
P(t) = (1-t)*P0 + t*P1
```

For example, for `t=0.25`, you compute `0.75 * P0 + 0.25 * P1`, which yields a point in the middle of the left half of the line between `P0` and `P1`.

For the case of De Casteljau's algorithm, the situation is a bit more involved: Depending on the degree of the curve, you don't interpolate between fixed points `P0` and `P1`, but between multiple points whose positions in turn depend on the variable `t`. This is usually computed recursively. But still, the variable `t` is a value between 0 and 1 that describes the position on the curve.

Answer (score 0):

Q = (1 − t) P1 + t P2, t ∈ [0, 1] is a parametrization of the line segment from P1 to P2, and t is its parameter. As t goes from 0 to 1, Q traverses the line segment from P1 to P2.

Note that that is valid for any P1 and P2 such that you can compute a linear combination of them. It's not necessary that P1 and P2 be points in R^n -- they could be matrices, for instance, or functions.